# How to configure selenium Web driver into Eclipse

Tags: selenium2

I want to Integrate the selenium Web driver test into eclipse, but i am really stuck at this point. Can any one help me at this point.

Comment: Welcome to SQA, @vinod guneja.  Can you be more specific about where you are stuck?

Comment: This is a meaningless question, you don't integrate code into a IDE, you write code with an IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please go through this blog where I have mentioned how to work with WebDriver, Eclipse and TestNG if you get more ideas about your question. 
http://www.anitpatel.net/2011/12/27/setting-up-selenium-web-driver-eclipse-testng/

Again, you question "how to inegrate..? is quite confusing so if the blog doesn't answer your question then please rephrase what exactly you were trying to do so that we can discuss more.

-Anit Patel

Answer (score 6):

Selenium Web Driver does not necessarily integrate with an IDE the way that many people think it would.  All that selenium is is a library. Import this library the way that you would any other in your code and in Eclipse, and it should work just fine.

I'm not sure if this answers what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I created a webdriver project using Maven+testng+webdriver on eclipse using this link.
Go through the link.its a step by step procedure.

http://blog.paxcel.net/blog/how-to-create-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse-with-maven-and-zkoss-support-2/

Answer (score -1):

This post could help you out:

http://www.softwaretestingclub.com/profiles/blogs/selenium-2-0-webdriver-how-to-configure-selenium-webdriver-in

Comment: Hi @Prateek-Jain - welcome to SQA! Given that links can change, we generally advise that if you're giving a link as an answer, that if possible you should give a summary of what the link includes. That way later readers can either try to find the information again even if the link is now dead, or at least get some idea of what your answer was. Write for the future too! :)